# MVC2 Model fields are null on postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to post back from a strongly typed view to my controller.

the problem is there are a couple of fields in the model that i dont want to allow the user to edit. ideally i just want to display them as labels but when i do that they're null when posted...

here's the relevant view code: this looks how i want it to look i.e. firstname and lastname are labels

```
 <td width="75px"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.FirstName, new{disabled="true"}) %></td>
          <td width="75px"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)%></td>
          <td width="100px"><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %></td>
          <td width="75px"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %></td>
          <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %></td>
```

Model looks like this:

public class PersonModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

}

the controller looks like this:

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RsvpToInvitation(PersonModel submittedRsvp)
        {...}

I've stripped a fair amount of code out of all of these... basically my question is how can i display a model property as a label and still post it back to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried storing the values with a `Html.Hidden` helper?

Comment: I was under the impression that hidden values dont get posted back either? let me try it

Comment: im wrong! it works. thanks for the super quick answer, thanks to Ken too!

Comment: @Dan, on StackOverflow you say "thanks" by upvoting answers.  Well, only the good ones :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make them hidden fields in your view.

```
<%: Html.Hidden("LastName", Model.LastName) %>
<%: Html.Hidden("EmailAddress ", Model.EmailAddress) %>
```